# How can I create these matrices?

Tags: java, matrix, binary

I have a table with products in rows and characteristics in columns.

I need to determine the products that are different from each other.

I would create a matrix for each product, comparing it with all the other products; for example, in the table for product1, the first row will be related to the product 2, and if the characteristic is different from product 1, value 1 will be written; the next row for product 3 and so on.

So, if I have 10 products, I'll need 10 matrices with 9 rows each.

How can I do this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you want to do this with matrices?

Comment: I need to determine how much the products are different, in order to determine how long does a setup take when I change the product currently in machining. If there's the value 1, the time of the operation related to the characteristic is activated. This is an information I'll put in an algorithm.
Thanks.

Comment: Or do you have any advice? Would you choose another way?